# Choose to borrow or pass ownership without duplicating code in Rust

Tags: rust

I wish I could choose to pass a ref or the thing itself without having to write the same function several times, like this:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

pub trait Add1<RHS=Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add1(&self, rhs: &RHS) -> Self::Output;
}



impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: Point) -> Point {
        Point { x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y }
    }
}

impl Add1 for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add1(&self, other: &Point) -> Point {
        Point { x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 0 };
    let p2 = Point { x: 2, y: 3 };
    let p4 = p1.add1(&p2);
    let p3 = p1 + p2;
    println!("{:?}", p3);
    println!("{:?}", p4);
}
```

How can avoid this kind of redundancy?

Comment: Your example seems to have multiple conflated concerns. There are two different traits involved and generally traits have different meanings so you wouldn't want to reuse them exactly. What are you *really trying to do*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) to abstract over the borrowed type

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl<T: Borrow<Point>> Add<T> for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: T) -> Point {
        Point { x: self.x + other.borrow().x, y: self.y + other.borrow().y }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 0 };
    let p2 = Point { x: 2, y: 3 };
    let p4 = p1.clone() + &p2;
    let p3 = p1 + p2;
    println!("{:?}", p3);
    println!("{:?}", p4);
}
```

Comment: Why `Borrow` and not `AsRef`?

Comment: `AsRef` is not implemented for all `T`, `Borrow` is.

Comment: Would `Cow` be helpful here?

Comment: @qed Using `Cow` would require creating `Cow` instances explicit in the call site,  `Cow` is an enum, not a trait.

Comment: Would be nice to able to do something like `impl<T> Add<T> for  T where T: Borrow<Point>`, but this leads to a E0210. How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot. The problem is that `Add` is foreign trait, and the rule is "only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter".

Answer (score 0):

What if you implement `Add` for `&Point`?

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: Point) -> Point {
        println!("refadd");
        Point { x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y }
    }
}

impl<'a> Add for &'a Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: &Point) -> Point {
        Point { x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 0 };
    let p2 = Point { x: 2, y: 3 };
    let p4 = &p1 + &p2;
    let p3 = p1 + p2;
    println!("{:?}", p3);
    println!("{:?}", p4);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address *How can avoid this kind of redundancy?*. Perhaps you can update it to do so?